# Jetpack Compose - How to manipulate the paste behaviour in a TextField

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to be able to manipulate the paste behaviour of an TextField, something along the lines of -

```
override fun onPaste(pastedText: String){
}
```

Like how an EditText has

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();     
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.paste:      
        break;     
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought of a workaround. When the paste happens, your value *usually* typically changes by more than 1 symbol, so ***maybe*** something like this will work. I know it is hacky, and I would rather write this as a comment, but comment limits will not let me describe it completely.

```
TextField(
    value = textValue,
    onValueChange = { newValue ->
        textValue = if (newValue.text.length > 1) {
            doSomething()
            newValue
        } else {
            newValue
        }
    }
)
```

UPD:

Oh I forgot that you can set up a modifier!

```
TextField(
    value = textValue,
    onValueChange = {...},
    modifier = Modifier
        .onKeyEvent { event: KeyEvent ->
            if (
                event.type == KeyEventType.KeyDown 
                && event.key == Key.Paste
            ) {
                 // DO SOMETHING
                 return@onKeyEvent true
            }
            false
        }
)
```

Comment: Using the paste key event, how would I get the pasted text?